# Lazy List copy (copy on write)

Tags: java, collections

Anyone aware of a List copy impl which only actually makes the copy when mutated? For read-dominated use cases it would (EDIT: may) be more efficient than `new ArrayList<>(oldList)`. Would be like `CopyOnWriteArrayList` except that it would only copy the elements zero or one times.

Example:

```
List list = Lists.lazyCopy(oldList);     // no copy
list.get(0);                             // delegate to oldList
list.set(0, null);                       // make a copy, mutate the copy
list.get(0);                             // read from copy
list.set(0, null);                       // mutate the copy, don't copy again
```

Comment: What would happen when the backing list is mutated?  (Answer: chaos.)  But seriously, `new ArrayList<>(oldList)` usually degenerates to a `System.arraycopy`, which is usually extremely fast.

Comment: Good point. But in my case oldList is a com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList

Comment: I would not be 100% certain that such data structure would necessarily be "more efficient" in read-dominated use cases because of the need to service the additional indirection: every single read will incur the cost of an additional check and a method call.

Comment: To follow up on 'dasblinkenlight' post, you may want to think about copy on read implementation.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, I'm motivated by GC impact moreso than CPU. This is otherwise a tight loop of arraycopys. I have edited the question to say 'may' instead of 'would'. There should really be an auto-fix for absolutes in SO :P

Answer (score -1):

As you mention in you comments that you have a `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList`: Why not use a simple `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` with your ImmutableList?

`CopyOnWriteArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` [simply uses the source collection's `toArray` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29) to create the backing array of the CopyOnWriteArrayList. And the non-singleton, non-empty RegularImmutableList's implementation of `toArray` also just does [one System.arraycopy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/13.0.1/com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableList.java#RegularImmutableList.toArray%28%29) from its own backing array to a new array. So, there is just one memory large allocation for the new backing array and a System.arraycopy, whosh should be quite fast in either case. Of course, a downside is the increased memory usage for the duplicated backing array.